# Pause timer if user presses up or down key, resume when they don't

Tags: c#, timer

I am running a routine set of activities with a timer in C#.

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
     RefreshTimer();
 }

 public void RefreshTimer()
 {
     var refreshTimer = new Timer();
     refreshTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => RefreshPlotList(sender, e);
     refreshTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => RefreshWatchList(sender, e);
     refreshTimer.Interval = 2000;
     refreshTimer.Enabled = true;
  }
```

How would I pause the timer if the user presses the up or down key, and then resume it after the key action is done?

Comment: It becomes trivial when you do *not* use System.Timers.Timer.  There is no point to it when you have to update UI when the timer ticks.

Comment: @HansPassant - have I gone about in a completely wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user presses a key set a boolean flag to record the fact that now the key is depressed. Clear the flag when the key is released.

Ignore timer tick events when the flag is set.

Or: Stop the timer when a key is pressed, start it when the key is released. This is less reliable because timer ticks might be queued and delivered after a key press.

Comment: Thanks. How would I ignore timer tick events when the flag is set? Can you please show me a rough example I can work off?

Comment: Add `if (keyIsPressed) return;` to the timer tick handler(s).

Comment: This is what I've done so far, am I on the right track? http://pastebin.com/aw6wzBgJ

Comment: Looks good. You better use the KeyEventArgs that is provided to you. The Keyboard class might give you out of date info if the user has very quickly released the button. KeyEventArgs gives you the actual event, not the current state.

Comment: Thanks. What is confusing me is how to keep track of when the user has pressed and released the key, especially as it seems that such things are handled differently in WPF. Do you have any good resources?

Comment: No, I don't have any at hand.

Comment: I've managed to finish it. Can you suggest any improvements, is my reasoning correct - http://pastebin.com/LCBvKVSf

Comment: You need to call RefreshTimer every time you change the bool variable. Otherwise it looks pretty good!